# Schedule VisualForce Extension and Actions

Tags: visualforce, controller, scheduled-apex

I'm getting out of my league with this little project so sorry if off base here. We have a custom button on a custom object page. Button calls VF page as listed below. Trying to see if we can easily create a scheduled class out of this so not tied to a button push? Scheduled class or maybe use time based workflow on the record to kick these off?

I understand the scheduable interface, etc. but I'm confused given that this starts with a VF page so not sure how/if can build a scheduable class for this?

**VF Page**

`apex:page standardController="Verification_Setting__c" extensions="GenerateHitController" action="{!Generate}">
/apex:page>`

**Extension and controller** are long but will post a snippet here:

  `private Verification_Setting__c verificationSetting = null;


public GenerateHitController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    verificationSetting = (Verification_Setting__c)controller.getRecord();
  }`

public PageReference Generate() {
    Verification_Setting__c setting = [SELECT Script_I__c...From Object where Id =: CustomObject.id];

Thanks for any direction here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply move the logic that you want to call from both the VF page and the scheduler to a scheduled class and a static method...

```
global class MyClass implements Schedulable{

 global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
    MyClass.generate(); 
  }

  global static void generate() {
    // do your stuff
  }

}
```

Now this class can be scheduled and it's static **generate()** method can still be called from your controller like so...

```
public PageReference generate() {
  MyClass.generate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Assuming you write a scheduler class as mentioned in scheduler class example

```
global class scheduledMerge implements Schedulable{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
   }
 }
```

this is how your method will be to call scheduler throgh Visualforce page after a minute delay or you can customize the delay

```
    public PageReference Generate(){

  datetime mydate = system.now();
        integer d = mydate.day();
        integer m = mydate.month();
        integer h = mydate.hour();
        integer s = mydate.second();
        integer min = mydate.minute();
        integer yr = mydate.year();
        if (min == 59)
        {
            min = 0;
            h = h + 1;
        }
        else min = min + 1;
        scheduledMerge addmerge = new scheduledMerge ();
        String sch = string.valueof(s) + ' ' + string.valueof(min) + ' ' + string.valueof(h) + ' ' + string.valueof(d) + ' ' + string.valueof(m) + ' ' + '?' + ' ' + string.valueof(yr);
        system.schedule('Address Merge Batch', sch, addmerge);

  retrun null;

}
```

Schedulre interface description:http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_scheduler.htm